# Android Cordova open app on notification

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification

I have a Cordova app which has a service for push notifications, push notifications are running fine, but when the notification arrives and I click on it the app is not starting.

Here is my IntentService:

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) { // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that
             * GCM will be extended in the future with new message types, just
             * ignore any message types you're not interested in, or that you
             * don't recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                // sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                // sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                // extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i + 1) + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                String message = extras.getString("message");
                String title = extras.getString("title");
                sendNotification(title, message);
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    private void sendNotification(String title, String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Uri uri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Intent intent = new Intent().setClassName("com.tojo.llynkr", "MainActivity");
        final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("buzz", "buzz");
        intent.putExtras(bundle);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
        mBuilder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(title + " | Llynkr ");
        mBuilder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(title));
        mBuilder.setContentText(msg);
        mBuilder.setSound(uri);
        mBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

BroadCastReceiver:

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

I also created MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // super.loadUrl("");
        Log.i("Notification Clicked", "************IT WORKED**********");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Manifest File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="0.0.1" package="com.tojo.llynkr" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <permission android:name="com.example.pushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.pushnotification.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale" android:label="@string/activity_name" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:name="CordovaApp" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/launcher_name">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.BootReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
        <service android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample.MyService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.red_folder.phonegap.plugin.backgroundservice.sample.MyService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

I tried all the possible solutions available but nothing seem to worked. Notifications arrives but when I click on it nothing happens.

Comment: Anything in `logcat`?

Comment: did you try cordova push plugin?
`cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git` [Check this](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

Comment: I cannot use PushPlugin as I need a background service, pushplugin I tried but not working as I expected